# How to switch nodes easily in a redis cluster cli?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a three node redis cluster.

If I run `cluster nodes` after I connect to one of the node via `redis-cli`, I got this output:

```
10.0.32.70:6379> cluster nodes
fedd7d9220ca59045782050e9c418103fdeee3bf 10.0.33.13:6379@1122 slave 56ada5e1cc30ba1889950df4c4203b856wc83558 0 1595241803685 2 connected
9eac3667c13055555555a52b20628da372dadc21 10.0.32.161:6379@1122 slave 81777bc32d3ff82da733e4b8f36a14e8de25e057 0 1595241801000 1 connected
861e7ed26924bcccccccaa23b1977982397000e7 10.0.33.231:6379@1122 slave 10397e832212231dc40ec687798f245a39007506 0 1595241802678 3 connected
10397e832212231dc40ec687798f245a39007506 10.0.32.117:6379@1122 master - 0 1595241801671 3 connected 10923-16383
81777bc32d3ff82da733e4b8f36a14e8de25e057 10.0.33.11:6379@1122 master - 0 1595241802000 1 connected 5462-10922
56ada5e1cc30ba1889950df4c4203b856wc83558 10.0.32.70:6379@1122 myself,master - 0 1595241801000 2 connected 0-5461
```

Now I want to switch to a different node from the current node.

When I use `select`, I got the following error:

```
> select 1
(error) ERR SELECT is not allowed in cluster mode
```

I can trigger a switch by using `get 1`, `get 2`... etc (Basically a get command with a random integer). A few trial and error will land me on the right node.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

you can try get **<**id of the node**>**. In your case.

```
get 10397e832212231dc40ec687798f245a39007506
get 81777bc32d3ff82da733e4b8f36a14e8de25e057
get 56ada5e1cc30ba1889950df4c4203b856wc83558
```

You can only connect to master nodes using get . If you try connecting to slave using get. It will connect to master node only.

Answer (score 0):

From inside redis-cli, you can also go:

```
connect 10.0.33.11 6379
```

Or on my test cluster

```
connect localhost 30002
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly useful trick: On my test cluster (via create-cluster command, 3-node, default mapping), by trial and error, I found 3 short keys which are faster to type to switch nodes:

```
get 3  (node 1)
get 1  (node 2)
get 4  (node 3)
```

(3.14, like PI)

You have to first run `redis-cli` with the `-c` option to auto-switch nodes when you set/get a key.

If your cluster-mapping is different, you can just start using get to find short somehow-memorable ones that work on your cluster. Obviously the cluster mapping can change in the future so you would not want to use this in any permanent scripts/code.